# C# WPF WindowsFormsHost control not exist in code

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

I added a winforms custom control on my wpf window.
The control shows in ui but when i trying to reach it inside code, im getting this error;

> "The name 'myCustomControl' does not exist in the current context"

Here is my XAML code;

```
 <WindowsFormsHost Width="300" Height="300" Grid.Row="1">
        <my:MyControl Dock="Fill" Name="myCustomControl"></my:MyControl>
 </WindowsFormsHost>
```

Sorry for my english

Comment: Please show relevant code

Comment: For the `my:MyControl` use `x:Name="myCustomControl"`. You then could get it with `MyControl myCtrl = this.FindName("myCustomControl") as MyControl;`

Comment: You don't need to use FindName. With `x:Name="myCustomControl"` a field `myCustomControl` will automatically be created. Which does not happen with `Name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `x:Name` instead of `Name`.

In contrast to WPF, setting  the `Name` property of a WinForms control does not automatically generate a field to access the control.

```
<WindowsFormsHost ...>
    <my:MyControl x:Name="myCustomControl" .../>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```